# Ethernet doesn't have a valid IP configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, modem

I got a new modem and router, same manufacturer, did my research spoke with  my isp and got my modem activated and configured.  My entire setup is hardwired. coax from pole to modem, cat5 from modem to router and cat5 from router to pc. Everything seemed to work but my speed is cut in half.

I then disconnected my pc from the router and directly to the modem. I have now met the speeds I'm used to getting BUT now my router (still connected to modem) is no longer transmitting WIFI. My modem shows activity going to it but now my WIFI is down. I power back down plug my pc back into my router and wifi works again. I then tried unplugging my pc from the router to my modem while everything is still powered on and my wifi stays on but now my ethernet is unidentifiable and get " Ethernet doesn't have a valid ethernet configuration".
Why am I not able to have my pc connected to my modem and still have wifi.

Already flushed dns, renewed ip, reset my tcp/ip stack and a lot of other things lol

NETGEAR Nighthawk Cable Modem CM1200
NETGEAR Nighthawk Smart Wi-Fi Router, R6700 - AC1750
this is the equipment i got

Answer (score 2):

A cable modem passes through a public IP address to the device connected behind it. Typically that is a router. The modem is essentially a network bridge. There is no routing capability or NAT, and no pool of private IP addresses that can be assigned to multiple devices. The multiple Ethernet ports are used for link aggregation or for multiple public IP addresses as outlined in the spec sheet: https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/modems/CM1200_DS.pdf

This is not the same as an all-in-one device from your ISP with modem, router and/or Wi-Fi all built in to one.

On most home internet connections you have a single, dynamic public IP address you can use. If you try to plug more than one device in to the cable modem it is only going to be able to assign that IP address to one of them. The other will be invalid.

Were you to have a pool of static IP addresses you can use from your ISP, you would be able to assign a unique IP address to each device. This is typical for business class services.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this makes alotta sense now. I had a feeling it was an ip conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I was also running into this exact same issue. I tried all the options available out there. Changing the cable, re-installing the driver, resetting the ipconfig, manually setting the DNS address etc etc. Nothing worked.

I played around with the modem's settings and to my surprise it worked.

I changed following settings:

> WAN Operation Mode: “Router Mode IPv4 + IPv6

to

> WAN Operation Mode: “Router Mode IPv4-Only"

Restarted the router. The ethernet was up and running. Didn't affect the wireless connection on the laptop.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.